# cmake didn't find my allegro includes and llibs so compile time error

Tags: c++, cmake, allegro

I am trying to set up my code to use the allegro libray, I am using the KDEV4 under mandriva, I installed the allegro-dev package. Then whenusing allegro functions in KDevelop it displays the documentation, so he surely found the library.

However when I compile my source I get `allegro_init()` not declared error, so I checked the `CMakeLists.txt` file and I think the problem is there:

```
project(game)
add_executable(game main.cpp)
```

What I should write to cmake to find and link the library?

I have a general installation where :

- includes are in `/usr/include`
- and libs are in `/usr/lib`

I installed allegro 4.4 under KDE 4.6.5 mandriva 2011 free, cmake 2.8.4.

If it is not obvious my question is what my CMakeLists.txt should looks like to compile with the allegro included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's maybe you forget to specify include path  or lib path.
If your allegro's head files locate in /usr/local/allegro/include
,and allegro's lib file whose name is liballegro.a locate in /usr/local/allegro/lib
Add following script resolve your problem perhaps.

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
/usr/local/allegro/include
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
   /usr/local/allegro/lib
) 

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game
liballegro.a 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to do it like this.

project(game)

add_executable(game main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(game -l{library})

Where {library} is the name if the  library which you need to link to your executable.

In your case i think it should be libalegro or something like that.

I suppose there is a better way, but I'm not very experienced with Cmake.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

actually i found that the right way of doing so is to add a CXX flag to the cmake using:

```
kdev options
```

and use a `'allegro-settings --libs'` that will return the right place of the includes and .O

and .a precompilled

sorry guys,thx but i will upvote you all

Comment: Could you please clarify this a bit more? Thx.

Comment: It is really unclear what you mean by this and how it is implemented.

Comment: the command 'allegro-settings --libs' will return the correct path to the lib

Comment: Could you say what you added to the CMakeLists.txt then? I don't really understand your answer.